# hardware switch is turned off for networking

Tags: hardware

My husband is in the hospital and his compaq6510b worked fine for a day with their WiFi.
The above message appeared when he turned off the computer and changed rooms.
help!

Comment: There is no above message.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though the wireless button was clicked and the wireless card was turned off.

from the HP/Compaq manual:

> The computer has a wireless button, one or more wireless devices, and
>   one or two wireless lights, depending on the model. All of the
>   wireless devices on your computer are enabled at the factory, so the
>   wireless light is on (blue) when you turn on the computer. The
>   wireless light indicates the overall power state of your wireless
>   devices, not the status of individual devices. If the wireless light
>   is blue, at least one wireless device is on. If the wireless light is
>   off, all wireless devices are off.

The button should be where the #4 circle is below.
[image: Compaq Wireless Button]